# Unable to resolve dependancies after adding firebase_database

Tags: flutter, dart, pubspec

I added 'firebase_database' to pubspec.yaml and got the following error:

[components] flutter pub get
Running "flutter pub get" in components...
Because firebase_core >=1.0.0 <1.1.1 depends on firebase_core_platform_interface ^4.0.0 and firebase_core >=1.1.1 depends on firebase_core_platform_interface ^4.0.1, firebase_core >=1.0.0 requires firebase_core_platform_interface ^4.0.0.

And because firebase_database >=6.1.2 <7.0.0-dev.1 depends on firebase_core ^1.0.3, firebase_database >=6.1.2 <7.0.0-dev.1 requires firebase_core_platform_interface ^4.0.0.

And because firebase_core_platform_interface >=4.0.0 depends on plugin_platform_interface ^2.0.0 and path_provider_platform_interface <2.0.0-nullsafety depends on plugin_platform_interface ^1.0.1, firebase_database >=6.1.2 <7.0.0-dev.1 is incompatible with path_provider_platform_interface <2.0.0-nullsafety.

And because shared_preferences_windows <0.0.3-nullsafety depends on path_provider_platform_interface ^1.0.3 and shared_preferences 0.5.12+2 depends on shared_preferences_windows ^0.0.1, if firebase_database >=6.1.2 <7.0.0-dev.1 and shared_preferences 0.5.12+2 then shared_preferences_windows ^0.0.3-nullsafety.

And because shared_preferences_windows >=0.0.3-nullsafety <2.0.0 depends on shared_preferences_platform_interface ^2.0.0-nullsafety and shared_preferences 0.5.12+2 depends on shared_preferences_platform_interface ^1.0.0, firebase_database >=6.1.2 <7.0.0-dev.1 is incompatible with shared_preferences 0.5.12+2.

So, because components depends on both shared_preferences 0.5.12+2 and firebase_database ^6.1.2, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because components depends on both shared_preferences 0.5.12+2 and firebase_database ^6.1.2, version solving failed.)
exit code 1

This is my list of dependancies:

```
 environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"  
  dependencies:
      flutter:
        sdk: flutter
      google_maps_flutter: ^1.0.6
      http: ^0.12.0
    
      
      json_serializable: ^3.3.0
      bloc: ^6.1.0
      flutter_bloc: ^6.1.0
      equatable: ^1.2.5
      graphql: ^4.0.1
      graphql_flutter: ^4.0.1
      flutter_google_places: ^0.2.4
      google_maps_webservice: ^0.0.16
      fluster: ^1.1.2
      flutter_cache_manager: ^1.4.1
      sliding_up_panel: ^1.0.2
      image: ^2.1.14
      flutter_svg: ^0.19.3
      lottie: ^0.6.0
      shared_preferences: '0.5.12+2'
      intl: ^0.17.0
      latlong: ^0.6.1
      polyline: ^1.0.2
      geolocator: ^5.3.1
      auto_size_text_field: ^0.1.7
      path_drawing: ^0.4.1
      flutter_native_timezone: ^1.0.10
      auto_size_text: ^2.1.0
      charts_flutter: ^0.10.0
      webview_flutter: ^2.0.4
      firebase_database: ^6.1.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the dependency of package.
but if you still want to run it just don't specify the version,

**just :**

ex

```
firebase_core:
firebase_database:
```